# My Kubernetes deployment keeps failing in jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy the popular sock shop app in my AWS EKS cluster. I have successfully created the cluster but whenever I try to deploy to the cluster I keep getting this error.

```
Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
-->

</body></html>
```

I have added my jenkins user to my sudo group but I still get same error. Also I tried to run this command directly on my ec2 instance

```
kubectl create -f complete-demo.yaml
```

And it deployed. What am I getting wrongs that keeps giving this error.

This is my Jenkins content

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "us-east-1"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Deploy to EKS") {
            steps {
                script {
                    dir('deploy/kubernetes') {
                        sh "kubectl create -f complete-demo.yaml"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the github profile I am deploying from.

https://github.com/Okeybukks/Altschool-Final-Cloud-Project

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find `EKS` deployment config anywhere in your GitHub repo. Just so you know that by default only user who had created the EKS cluster has only access to its Kubernetes API , you have to add I am users or IAM Role in the aws_auth_configmap to enable other user access which could be your Jenkins user in this case if that's not the same user which created the cluster. 
reference doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

Comment: I am using eksctl to create my eks clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `EC2` instance and some AWS credentials please make sure that user connected with those creds is listed in `aws-auth` configmap located in `kube-system` namespace.

If yes then you should probably run `EKS` login command before you apply your manifest to be able to generate proper `config` file which is not present in `Jenkins` workspace. So your pipeline should looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "us-east-1"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Deploy to EKS") {
            steps {
                script {
                    dir('deploy/kubernetes') {
                        sh """
                           aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my_cluster_name
                           kubectl create -f complete-demo.yaml
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cluster-connection/) doc regarding login to `EKS`.